# Have SSIS handle random sized column in CSV file

Tags: ssis

I have a csv file i'm trying to import into SQL.

I've found that in one row, a column has a different size to the rest..

I.e. the column is length 4 for all columns except one, where it is 10 for some reason.

Not sure why it happened.

Is there a way for SSIS to handle this anomaly?

Comment: Set the length of the data type as 10? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The schema of the csv file you are going to read is not dynamically set.
You may have to edit it manually at design time.
For this case, as billinkc said, setting the length of the data type to a relative maximum number would be sufficient.